# HTML progress bar with custom background color has design problem if it has low values

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, progress-bar

This custom CSS progress bar works with value `500` over 1000, but fails with value `5` over 1000:

**How to avoid this unesthetic vertical line on the left?** (browser: Chrome)

[image]

```css
progress { appearance: none; }
progress::-webkit-progress-value { border-radius: 10px; background-color: #00122c; }
progress::-webkit-progress-bar { border: 1px solid #00122c; border-radius: 10px; background-color: white; }
```

```html
<progress color="red" value="5" max="1000" ></progress>
<progress color="red" value="500" max="1000" ></progress>
```

Comment: add the same radius to `progress` and hide the overflow

Comment: Thanks @TemaniAfif ! If you post as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the border-radius and border definition to the progress element and hide the overflow:

```css
progress {
  appearance: none;
  border-radius: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #00122c;
}

progress::-webkit-progress-value {
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: #00122c;
}

progress::-webkit-progress-bar {
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<progress color="red" value="5" max="1000"></progress>
<progress color="red" value="500" max="1000"></progress>
```